# Custom content assist template for java annotations on methods

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse 3.6, I can't seem to get the following content assist template to work:

```
@Column(name="${cursor}")
```

Whenever I try `ctrl-spc` on a start string such as `@C` it only shows me the usual type completions, no additional entries (like the one I see when starting a `for` for instance). The help seems to be light on detail on how the pattern should look. Is content assist supposed to work for annotations? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the template without the `@` ... such that you type `co<crtl-spc>` and then let generate `@Column(name="${cursor}")`.

Comment: Cheers! For some reason I thought it matches the pattern and not the name of your template. This helped clarify it for me.